# Ubuntu Systemd script does not execute correctly

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

Systemd on Ubuntu 16.04 does not do what I want.

Here is my script (/usr/bin/testscript) writes some line into /tmp/pa.log:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "query pacmd" >> /tmp/pa.log

/usr/bin/pacmd list-sinks >> /tmp/pa.log

echo "done" >> /tmp/pa.log
```

If I run:

```
$ /usr/bin/testscript
$ cat /tmp/pa.log
query pacmd
2 sink(s) available.
  * index: 99
  ... (lot of stuff which does not matter here)
done
```

I want to run this from a systemd service, so I created one (/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio-remote-sink.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Desc
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
User=xy ###this is my username of course
Group=xy ###this is my group of course
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/testscript

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
WantedBy=default.target
```

And I enabled it and tried:

```
$ systemctl enable test.service
$ systemctl start test.service
```

But now, in the log file there is no output from pacmd:

```
$ cat /tmp/pa.log
query pacmd
done
```

Why does this systemd service behaves like this? How can I achieve the same result as if I run it manually?

Comment: Read the answer to [this FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645#339645) and check the output of `journalctl -u test`

Comment: Thanks, that was very valuable. PulseAudio needs 'PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH' environment variable which was not defined in systemd.